# Privilege to set default database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions

It turns out that a user cannot set default database if it does not have global (`mysql.user`) or any database-level permissions (`mysql.db`):

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'XXX'@'%' to database 'mysql'
```

However, using default database could be convenient, e. i. there is a lot old scripts relying on that.

The only workaround I've found so far, is to grant SHOW VIEW on the database: I do not want to grant even read-only access for all tables.

What do I miss? I don't know any SQL syntax that allows insert 'N' in all relevant columns in `mysql.db`, and don't want to do it with raw SQL (`INSERT ...`).

Comment: you may grant usage if you want to give just the connect access to some user, couldn't get what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Your statement is not quite correct.  Your `root` probably has no entry in `mysql.db`, yet has no trouble with `USE`.  Please give an example of _both_ the `GRANT` and `USE` that cause trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks Rick James, it is a bit more complicated. The problem is with MariaDB.

Update: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9614